# maximum quota reached but cannot adjust

Tags: quota

I am not an experienced sharepoint user, but can get around sites already created. I am getting emails to advise me that our 500MB quota limit has been reached, but when i use sharepoint 3.0 central administration, on the site collection quotas and locks page, i attempt to find the page which was sent in the email, i am advised the error message "no site was found that begins with http://etc etc.
All the sites have been created and central admin was already running on the server.
Can anyone advise please ?

Answer (score 0):

couple of things to check.

- check the url of the site collection.
- go to the Central admin > application management > configure the quota and locks
- on the top right hand side click the dropdown and new pop up, Select the web app 1st then the site collection.
- Now you will see the quota of site collection and adjust it accordingly.

https://jimecox.wordpress.com/2012/02/14/sharepoint-2007-quotas-locks-control-db-size-how-to-tips-etc/